# What is libstdc++-libc and when need it

Tags: c++, linux, libstdc++

Anyone can be kind enough to tell me what is libstdc++-libc.so, and when we need it?
I find it in /usr/lib,however i can't find it in /usr/lib64. (Fedora 20 64bits)

Comment: ahh sorry i guess i mis-understood your question

Answer (score 0):

I'm 99% confident that 'libstdc++-libc' is a `libstdc++.so` library compiled with an older *glibc*, this lib is provided in RedHat-based distro in the `compat-libstdc++` package.

**I suppose** that this permits the compilation of software with older *glibc* versions, this permits to run the generated binaries on all the Linux OSes based on higher *glibc* versions (*glib* is back-compatible, it can run binaries compiled on older glibc versions).

I cannot check 100% this statement, that is based on previous readings, because I currently work on Ubuntu/Debian based distros.